# Android Parent Activity Button on top of all Child Activities

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-activity, fragment

So here is my problem and Question

I have a Header and Footer layout in a Main.xml and its FragmentActivity is Main.java.

Now this header and footer is common across all activities in my application as shown by Image.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pgox67k33u0zxct/device-2013-10-23-002417.png

So to solve this problem i used Fragments as Shown in Figure Main.java Fragment A is inside Main.xml . Now this all works fine Fragment A is showing header and footer of Main.xml

Problem starts when i start an activity from Fragment A it totally opens in a New Window full screen . My understanding was if i start an Activity from Fragment A then this Activity will only take place of Fragment A . I hope you understand my question .

Answer (score 0):

Re-using Layouts with `<include/>`

Define your Header and Footer layout

and use that like

```
 <include layout="@layout/header"/>
```

and

```
<include layout="@layout/footer"/>
```

e.g

```
<include
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   layout="@layout/header" />
```

Go through Android Document

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Comment: yes this can be one approach of doing it but from Architecture Point of view it seems wrong . As we are reusing same thing multiple time . What i am trying to achieve is main activity and child activity relation

Comment: So think of this that header and footer have alot of functionality and I want to keep it in the Parent Context and then child activities loading in the rest of the space.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using activities in such case?
It seems that fragments would be more convenient for this type of problem especially since you want that header/footer are used from Parent activity.

so you would have in your xml:

- header
- framelayout (this would be replaced by fragment within activity)
- footer

Each of the fragments have its own lifecycle and parent activity as well.
You can find example of this in Android documentation:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Well i was looking into this fragments . And your answer seems right to me i think fragments are build exactly for this purpose.  Can You please explain a little bit more to me how should i design my architecture with child activities

Comment: Well if you want to control header and footer from parent activity then you can do main.xml as i've wrote in post. Then within your activity, create methods for switching fragments with FragmentManager which you can call depending on events. Each Fragment has its own xml layout which you inflate when creating it, and you can call methods from parent activity by requesting activity in your fragment with getActivity() method. Each Fragment will take place of FrameLayout in activity between your header and footer as defined in xml.

Comment: Thanks man for the 2nd opinion as i am going to start a very huge application and i dont want to make mistakes at architecture level. So i needed a second opinion which i got from you.So thanks again i will follow this now.

Comment: i have updated my question please can you take a look at this one.

Comment: You should not start new activity. Just replace Fragment A with Fragment B and but the Activity B logic inside Fragment B.

Comment: So if i replace Fragment A with Fragment B and from Fragment B to Fragment C and so on . Then how will startActivityForresult will work ?

Comment: Lets say Fragment A starts Fragment B and Fragment B starts Fragment C . Now Fragment C is a game and i want the back button to work like activities that when i press back button last activity should be loaded. So by your approach if i am converting Activities to fragments and replacing them in Main.java then don't you think by replacing them i will loose the last fragment state and also the method startActivityfor result

Comment: No not if you call addToBackStack in fragment transaction, then your back button will call previous fragment on screen. It is very clearly described in the android documentation. startActivityForResult is called if you want result received back from started activity. All results will be posted to your parent activity from which you can delegate them to fragment.

Comment: OK let me give this a shot.